# why is this numberformat exception thrown even when its defined for double

Tags: java, exception

Formate is defined for double right? Is there a better way to do this without using big decimals? Maybe with the Math environment, and this casting is not that nice. So why is it being thrown when halfup means to the next integer?

````java
static String abfallEimer(double d, boolean runden)
    {
        String s = "";

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
        nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        // BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
        // bd = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        // d = bd.longValueExact();
        d = new Long(nf.format(d));

        if (d > 1000 && !runden)
        {
            long kaki = Math.round(d / 1000) * 1000;

            if (d > 1000000)
            {
                kaki /= 1000000;
                s = nf.format(kaki) + " Mill.";
                return s;
            }
            else
            {
                s = nf.format(kaki);
                return s;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            long kaki = (long) d;
            s = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(kaki);
            return s;
        }

    }```
````

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,5"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:707)
at java.base/java.lang.Long.(Long.java:1344)
at GBO/gui.country.combo.Country.abfallEimer(Country.java:82)
at GBO/gui.country.combo.CountryInfo.lambda$0(CountryInfo.java:124)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
at ...

Comment: Please include the stacktrace in any question about exceptions thrown at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is on this line:

```
  d = new Long(nf.format(d));
```

What you are doing there is converting a `double` to a string ... with a decimal point in it ... and then trying to parse that as an integer.  Naturally, the integer parser throws an exception.

(This can be confirmed by reading the exception + stacktrace that you added, which even includes the string that it was attempting to parse.)

Here's what the javadoc for `Long(String)` says in Java 11:

> **Deprecated.** It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Use `parseLong(String)` to convert a string to a `long` primitive, or use `valueOf(String)` to convert a string to a `Long` object.
>
> Constructs a newly allocated `Long` object that represents the `long` value indicated by the String parameter. The string is converted to a `long` value in exactly the manner used by the `parseLong` method for radix 10.

So that explains why your code is throwing the exception.

What is unclear to me is what you are actually trying to do on that line.  If you are simply trying to convert a `double` to a `long`, there are simpler ways to do it;

```
   long l = (long) d;       // truncates towards zero; see the
                            // JLS 4.2.4 explanation of IEE 754
                            // "round towards zero" conversions.
   long l = Math.round(d);  // rounds, biased to +infinity; see javadoc
```